# How to read several .txt* files in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, readfile

Actually, I can read one txt.* config-file (VALUES) and check a content.

In main program in case 1, I'm getting a settings and set a measurement:

```
// *******************************************************************    
// Main
// *************

case PREPARE_MEASURE:{

qDebug()<<"Debug: PREPARE_MEASURE";

QStringList lines = m_conf->getConf_lines();


//another part of code.....

//********************************************************************
// Config-Class
// *************

#include "Conf.h"
#include "Audio.h"
#include "Measure.h"

// **************

Conf::Conf()
{
    m_cfile = new QFile();
    load_conf(VALUES);
}

// ***************
// Get & Set audio-configuration

void Conf::load_conf(QString file_name)
{

    m_cfile->setFileName(file_name);
    m_cfile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    while(!m_cfile->atEnd())
    {
        m_conf_lines.append(m_cfile->readLine());
    }

    for(int32_t i = 0 ; i < m_conf_lines.size() ; i++)
    {

        QString chunk = m_conf_lines.at(i);

        if(chunk.contains("=") == true)
        {
            QStringList key_value = chunk.split("=");

            if(key_value.at(0) == "samp_rate")
            {
                this->samp_rate = key_value.at(1).toUInt();
                setSampRate(samp_rate);
                qDebug()<< key_value.at(0);
            }

            //another part of code

            if(key_value.at(0) == "sample_type")
            {
                this->samp_type = key_value.at(1);
                setSampType(samp_type);
            }

          }//end if(chunk.contains("=")
      }//end for(int32_t i = 0


}//end void Conf::load_conf

// ****************
// Get values from config file

QStringList Conf::getConf_lines() const
{
    return m_conf_lines;
}

//*****************
```

In case 2 I'm making a measure, in case 3 I'm stopping a measure.

Now, I want to make several measures and be able read lot of VALUES config-txt files each after other.

The program should be work:

- read Value1 > Set Settings 1 > Making measure 1 > go to second Value
- read Value2 > Set Settings 2 > Making measure 2 > go to third Value
- .........

How is it possible? Thank you

Comment: You read several files the same way you read 1 file but instead you have a loop.

Comment: `m_cfile = new QFile();` is better to not use a dynamic allocation for this.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried already to make a loop around `load_conf(VALUES);` but it not works, or I think wrong?

Comment: dynamic allocation? you mean to use a pointer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just beginner in C++

Comment: You don't need for a pointer to CFile. Just use `CFile m_cfile;`

Comment: Modern `c++` urges you to never use `new` although `Qt` does conflict with that a when it comes to  the parent / child relationship between `QObject` classes. In the case of QFile you don't have this and don't really benefit from dynamic allocation.